# Libgdx - how to zoom a rectangle/line (shaperenderer)

Tags: libgdx, border, shapes

Let's say that I have an `Actor` which has a draw method:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch,parentAlpha);

        sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        sr.setColor(Color.RED);
        sr.rectLine(getX(),getY(),getX() + getWidth(),getY(),3);
        sr.end();
}
```

As you can see, the actor also draws a red line below itself.
Now, when I zoom the camera on a stage, where the actor is, he becomes bigger - it works **but his red rectangle doesn't.**

When I set `debug()` on the `Actor`, it shows the debug lines and **zooms them aswell**.

***What I'm trying to achieve?***

I need to zoom the line too, along the actor.

If there's anyone who knows how to achieve this, I would be grateful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shaperenderer is similar to batch. It has own coordinate matrix.
So you need to set projection matrix on shaperenderer too.

```
shaperenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

It will probably work for you.

But while shaperenderer drawing via vertexes, lines' width may not change even when you zoom in/out.

You can change line width with openGL function.

```
Gdx.gl.glLineWidth(width);
```

And additionaly im suggesting not to use Shaperenderer because its quite expensive class and only recommended for debug drawings.